# How to remove first bullet while deleting all the list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

since it is editable so when i click on list and want to delete all the item

but the first list `bullet point`(1.) is not deleting.

```html
<h2>An ordered HTML list</h2>

<ol contentEditable="true">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

how do i remove `1.` also while deleting all the items(ctrl A)?

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript?

Comment: how ?? i dont have any idea

Comment: No repro on Firefox 50.1.0 -- I can delete the first bullet point.

Comment: It works for me, delete all the content, then press backspace once more to remove the `1.` caused by the presence of the first `li` element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want to remove with one click only . no backspace

Comment: @Mahi thats not how it works, everywhere. :D

Comment: I don't think you can using the native contenteditable. You have to delete once for the content of the `li`, then again to delete the `li` itself.

Comment: @Mahi everyone's correct. You'll need at least 2 backspace presses to delete *all* the items. If you want a button that deletes the entire list, you can do that.

Comment: but why there is `1.` left ??

Comment: Because it's a list.

Comment: and because it requires also some space to click in to actually start to edit something ....

Comment: @obarakon can you solve then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ol=document.getElementById('list');
ol.oninput=function(e){
  var list=$('ol li');
  list.filter(function() {return $(this).text()== '';}).remove();
  if(ol.innerHTML==="")
    ol.remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>An ordered HTML list</h2>

<ol id='list' contentEditable="true">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: can i remove `ol` tag completely

Comment: @Mahi updated now the ol is deleted if no li are in it